# Selected options in Django variable

Tags: html, django

How to save the selected options from a multi select drop down in a Django variable as a list ? Is there anything to be imported from the .html to .py?

Comment: maybe you meant how get value from multiple dropdown  in Django views ?

Comment: Basically, I want to make use of that list in a python script(not views).

Answer (score 0):

To get the values from multiple dropdown  the method is:

**Template(myPage.html):**

```
<select multiple="multiple"  name="services" id="services" size="5">
    {% for service in services %}
        <option value="{{ service.pk }}">{{ service.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

**Views(views.py):**

```
myServices = request.POST.getlist('services')
```

good luck..!!

Comment: Like there are over 600 options. Should I enter service.pk for all 600 options??

Comment: where should I type this?

Comment: each of the options must have its id(pk), Django by default define the "ID" in this case is "id-> autoincrement integer"

Comment: i suggest implement this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917791/how-create-multiple-select-box-in-django